# strange greek characters in google kaptcha

Tags: spring-mvc

I've use google kaptcha to generate captcha for verification, it worked good on my own pc, but after deployed to production, the character became like greek or something. It looks like below.

[image]

It is really strange. Did anyone meet this problem before?

Comment: May it is one time thing, try refreshing the browser. I have not seen this. cheers.

Comment: unfortunately it's always like this in the production environment.

Comment: I have the same problem. On my machine it works fine but when I publish it I get on  some machines the same strange characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the missing fonts on your production system. See [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/jira-ui-shows-unreadable-text-or-nothing-on-captcha-and-some-gadgets-due-to-missing-fonts-941590036.html) for more details.